# Rotator Cuff Training

Tags: shoulders, rotator-cuff, shoulder-cuff

Should I train my rotator cuff before or after a workout and how many days a week should I train it. Somebody also hit me up with a good routine for the rotator cuff.

Answer (score 2):

I think that "warming up rotator cuff muscle before weight lifting and workout" is good.But if you work out a lot rotator cuffs then you are exhausting your rotator cuffs and rotator cuffs can't stabilize your shoulder.

Answer (score 2):

Isolation training for your RO Cuff (in a non-rehab setting) is inefficient and unnecessary as it's already activated during more complex exercises.

---

You're body moves as a unit and muscles never act in isolation. Your rotator-cuff should not be trained "alone" as it a critical dynamic stabilizer for the most unstable joint in your body, your shoulder.

---

> **Here's one Progression:** 
>  Chop and Lift (**1/2 Kneel** >> **Tall Kneel** >> **Standing**).

[image]

---

Utilize Exercises that incorporate Diagonal Patterns *(Known as D2 Flexion and Extension)*

---

[image]

Comment: But athlean x says that training the rotator cuff helps in big lifts.

Comment: Scapular Retraction and External Rotation (Ext Ro) will help with Bench for example...  The diagonals are indeed training these same muscle except in a functional pattern.

Comment: Similar to your core - if you can't stabilize your shoulder & scapula this will greatly effect other lifts.  They are dynamic stabilizers (i.e your lower trap, rhomboids, teres major, subscap) -- simply meaning they hold the head of your humerus in your "shoulder" socket with overhead lifts, presses etc...

Comment: Not isolating muscles = no muscles. If you can't get massive biceps just fron chin ups and you can't .you also can't get a strong rotator cuff with just compound exercises.

Comment: And this day functional training is just some non sense overused word. What does it even mean functional training? Functional for who and for what? Something functional can't work for everyone if everyone trains for different purposes

Comment: You're mind only can learn movement patterns.  Muscles don't work in isolation - ever.  http://graycookmovement.com/ may help.

Comment: If you want to train muscles in "isolation" you're welcome to.  Just like I don't  have a pedal only day when I ride a bike I train how we move (push pull, UE, LE etc)